# Using ASP.NET, how can I create an iPhone/Android specific mobile website?

Tags: asp.net, iphone, mobile, jqtouch

I would like to take [our current mobile website](http://grok.lsu.edu/mobile) and redesign it for iPhone use. All of the code on our website is currently run server-side and is split up in multiple pages, but I would like to get all the client-side features like transition animations and iPhone-like buttons that jQTouch offers. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice google project that uses CSS to mimic the iPhone UI... Its called IUI... Below is the link to the Google Code project.

http://code.google.com/p/iui/

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow morning at work. Is this more friendly with ASP.NET than jQTouch? The ASP.NET controls seemed to break my jQTouch pages.

Comment: I ended up sticking with jQTouch. I was able to figure out the cause of my troubles.